# Git: Push to a remote repository with a message

Tags: git, message

My company is incorporating iRise for prototyping and it lacks any kind of versioning (unless making copies of your files with different file names = versioning). Anyway, we're using Git for our version control and since the typical iRise user here will be a graphic/web designer I want to automate the process as much as possible. I have a hot folder running an AppleScript that will push to a remote repository but I'm not sure how to add a message...

```
git push TestProject master
```

tried

```
git push TestProject master -m 'message'
```

but threw a switch error and showed a list of options, -m not being one of them...

is this possible or do you have to commit locally first and then push that to the remote and the message will be attached with it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You will have to do a commit ( after adding files)

```
git commit -m 'message'
```

and then push:

```
git push TestProject master
```

You cannot associate a message to the push.

Comment: Thanks, any idea what the reasoning is for that?

Comment: "The reasoning" for that is that 'push' is copying commits from one repository to another. So you have to have a commit for it to copy.

Comment: BTW commit has an option `--allow-empty` that might be useful for your purpose

Comment: With GitHub you could incorporate a pull-request into your process (with every push, for example) that would effectively allow you to add comments with each pull-request. You can incorporate pull-request comments with the aid of a simple script or from command-line using GitHub hub.

Answer (score 11):

I think the question is legitimate, and is not completely answered by the answer above. Here is a workflow we use at our company (we use git flow):

1. git flow feature start myFeature
2. git commit -m 'commit for feature myFeature prior to code review'
3. initiate code collaborator review with the commit above.
4. git commit -m 'commit for code review comments/changes for myFeature round1'
5. <same as above, maybe round2>
6. git flow feature finish myFeature

   - *this merges to local develop branch, and deletes myFeature branch*
7. git push origin develop

Now it would be real nice if we could add a message like this during the push Step 7. like this:

```
git push -m 'Feature is code complete, code collaborator review ids 1234, 1235.' origin develop
```

Definitely, not a trivial case where someone is trying to push without commits, but a very useful step where you are annotating a specific push with metadata that provides some audit trail.

Comment: Yes, I agree. In my case, I am pushing after a new clone. I'd like a message to say where I cloned from. As  newbie , I do not see that info readily available. Being able to easily track the origin of a branch is something SVN does really well. I want to mimick that.

Comment: How is anyone able to review code without iit being pushed to remote repo. Are they reviewing by after coming to developers machine? AFAIK commit is a local process :)

Comment: I have the similar problem, I merged staging branch commits to the master  and it shows nothing to commit, working tree clean. Now, I need to push the changes but unable to add any comments.